# Is it necessary to create a new table if I have two tables with common column names? SQL Best practices

Tags: database, database-design

**I need help to do a good database analysis and learn**

I have two tables:

- Patient
- Specialist

These two tables have column names in common:

- first_name
- last name
- level of education
- e-mail
- phone

Is it necessary to create a new table with these elements in common and that they are related to the other two tables?

or

It is not necessary in this case. I try to make a good analysis and apply good practices

**PICTURE BELOW HERE**

[ER_Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjMJE.png)

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; retag the RDBMS you are really using and **only** that RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

These are just suggestions and not an answer.

Kind of very small questions, but very difficult to answer because answers may contradict each while explaining.

> explenation

That depends on your requirement actually. for example,

1. How many records that you going to manage inside a table?

   - if it is comparably small, you can keep both patients and specialists on the same table with a flag to categorize them.
   - comparably big, you can keep **Patient** and **specialist** tables separately with common fields inside each table.
2. What level of segregation do you expect from your system?
   For example in microservices, keeping two different tables is better to isolate each service. But that also depends on the architecture you're going to use.

But separating common fields into a different table and managing those fields are not necessary like what we are doing with OOP concepts. because unwanted DB relations give you an extra burden to your queries.

This is my idea. You can have many from others :)